# Tapping to place the cursor at end of paragraph fails in the iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

When editing in the iOS app, the cursor will not go where you tap.   If you tap at the end of a paragraph, it puts the cursor in a magic location in the beginning of the next paragraph.  This is most pronounced when adding to the end of the body text of a posting with links or images.

[image]

Note in the picture how the cursor has landed after the `[` in the URL tag.  I clicked to the right of the `?` in the paragraph before.